# Path not being found in Windows via bash/python script

Tags: python, windows, bash, csv

This is `.csv` file containing `target,path`:

```
[root@server ~]# head /usr/local/CustomAppResults/App/targets.txt 
server1.com,C:\\Program Files\\App\\
```

I loop through the `.csv`, line by line in a `Bash` script ..

```
IFS=","
while read target path
do
    # Windows target
    result=$(python /root/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/App/tools/remoteStafCommand.py "$target" "dir $path /B")
    resultCode=$?
    echo "$result"
done
```

The `bash` script passes the contents of the `csv.` file into a `Python` script, it's contents are below.
The `Python` script runs a `staf` subprocess and parses the results, which is returned and stored inside `result` of the `Bash` script.

```
[root@server ~]# cat App/tools/remoteStafCommand.py 
import subprocess,re,sys
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, check_output

print "1st arg: %s" % (sys.argv[1])
print "2nd arg: %s" % (sys.argv[2])

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(["staf", "%s" % (sys.argv[1]) , "PROCESS", "START", "SHELL", "COMMAND", "%s" % (sys.argv[2]), "WAIT", "RETURNSTDOUT", "STDERRTOSTDOUT"])
    result = re.findall(r'Data\s*:\s*((?:[^\n]*(?:[\r\n]+(?!\s*}))?)+)', output, re.DOTALL)[0]
    print result
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.returncode)
    sys.exit(e.returncode)
```

This is the output I get, why can it not find the path? It exists.

```
1st arg: server1.com
2nd arg: dir C:\Program Files\App\ /B
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Why do you capture the output into `result` if all you do is `echo` it? Just let Python print the result to standard output. Similarly, you are capturing and then immediately losing the exit code for no apparent reason.

Comment: I parse `result` after the while loop and use `resultCode` later too but it wasn't relevant to question.

Comment: Still, `python script.py` is better than `result=$(python script.py); echo "$result"` and the results from earlier iterations of the loop won't be available after the loop anyway. Better still would be to make the script produce machine-readable output directly; the caller already has the metainformation you print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping `path` with double quotes directly in `.csv` file for escaping ..

```
[root@server ~]# head /usr/local/CustomAppResults/App/targets.txt 
server1.com,"C:\\Program Files\\App\\"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `read` command tokenizes on whitespace, not comma. You can override this by changing the value of `IFS`. Or if the text file isn't used for anything else, change its format to have a space instead of a comma between the fields. Or better still, have your Python script read and parse the file directly -- the simple Bash script begs to be factored away.

Comment: Updated question, I already set `IFS=","` before the bash `read`